# Chronological table : title column on the left or right?

Tags: tables, column

I am working on a chronological table which display the measures taken for each day.
The most valuable information is commonly the latest one so it has to be displayed near to the label. But if the title column is on the left, the measures won't respect the chronological order which is from left to right.

[image]

The other option is to set the title column on the right but is it acceptable and understandable ?
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here depends largely on the native or common languages for your users. If they are predominantly in left-to-right reading countries, title columns are best placed on the left (identify the row you're seeing, then see the data in that row). Likewise, if your users are predominantly in right-to-left reading countries, reverse that.

The goal is to make accessing your table a trivial task. This is done by leveraging the natural way we scan information.

Titles > headers > labels > guts of the data.

Understanding this, we want our data visualizations to line up with how people read and scan objects to make getting to the data as quick as possible.

Also, to note, if the table is wider than the individual user's browser area, putting the row labels on the predominant start-side means they will see the labels and have their context. Were the labels on the non-predominant side, the user may not see the labels and would instead be disoriented.